# How to give a process exclusive cpu access for a certain amount of time?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, system-calls, scheduling

**General Description:**
I'm trying to implement a system call which does the following:

- Accepts an argument representing number of seconds.
- Schedules the calling process with exclusive access to the cpu for the given amount of time.
- If after the given amount of time passes the process hasn't exited, go back to normal scheduling.
- If the calling process went to sleep while having exclusive access to the cpu, let the cpu idle.
- If the calling process dies while having exclusive access, go back to normal scheduling.

**System:**

- RedHat 8.0 - kernel version 2.4.18 with the O(1) scheduler as implemented in version 2.5.21.
- Running as a VM on VMware Workstation 16.
- A single CPU core.

**Attempted solution:**
My idea was to set up a timer for the given duration, assign a SCHED_FIFO scheduling policy with MAX_RT_PRIO - 1 realtime priority, and have the timer function reassign the original policy (SCHED_OTHER) when the timer expires.

**Problem:**
Although only changing the policy and priority as above works (when not using the timer), the system freezes when I set up the timer - the CAPS key start flashing and I have no choice but to shut down the VM.

**Code:**
First, I defined a `struct` in `sched.h` which is located in the kernel subdirectory include/linux:

```
typedef struct {
    task_t *p;
    int prio;
    int static_prio;
    unsigned long policy;
    unsigned long rt_priority;
} magic_sched_params_t;
```

Next, in kernel/sched.c I defined a function that receives two pointer to above `struct`s, saves the current values to the second `struct` and assigns the values of the first `struct` to the process, much like the setscheduler() function in the same file:

```
void magic_set_policy(magic_sched_params_t *new_params, magic_sched_params_t *old_params)
{
    runqueue_t *rq;
    prio_array_t *array;
    unsigned long flags;
    task_t *p = new_params->p;

    read_lock_irq(&tasklist_lock);
    rq = task_rq_lock(current, &flags);
    
    if (old_params) {
        old_params->p = current;
        old_params->prio = p->prio;
        old_params->static_prio = p->static_prio;
        old_params->policy = p->policy;
        old_params->rt_priority = p->rt_priority;
    }

    array = p->array;
    if (array)
        deactivate_task(p, task_rq(p));
    p->policy = new_params->policy;
    p->rt_priority = new_params->rt_priority;
    if (p->policy != SCHED_OTHER)
        p->prio = MAX_USER_RT_PRIO-1 - p->rt_priority;
    else {
        p->prio = new_params->prio;
        p->static_prio = new_params->static_prio;
    }
    if (array)
        activate_task(p, task_rq(p));

    task_rq_unlock(rq, &flags);
    read_unlock_irq(&tasklist_lock);
}
```

System call and timer function implementation: (added to the "kernel" subdirectory in a separate file)

```
extern void magic_set_policy(magic_sched_params_t *new_params, magic_sched_params_t *old_params);

void on_timer_end(unsigned long old_params)
{
    magic_sched_params_t *old_sched_params = (magic_sched_params_t *) old_params;
    magic_set_policy(old_sched_params, NULL);
    kfree(old_sched_params);
}

int sys_magic_clock(unsigned int seconds)
{
    struct timer_list timer;
    unsigned long expire = jiffies + seconds * HZ;
    magic_sched_params_t new_params = { 0 };
    magic_sched_params_t *old_params = kmalloc(sizeof(magic_sched_params_t), GFP_KERNEL);

    if (!old_params)
        return -ENOMEM;

    new_params.p = current;
    new_params.policy = SCHED_FIFO;
    new_params.rt_priority = MAX_RT_PRIO - 1;

    init_timer(&timer);
    timer.function = on_timer_end;
    timer.data = (unsigned long) old_params;
    timer.expires = expire;
    add_timer(&timer);

    magic_set_policy(&new_params, old_params);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Any help with what the root cause of the problem might be and possible solutions - even alternative routes to take to achieve the goals mentioned in the general description - would be much appreciated.

Comment: I don't think any scheduling scheme will let the CPU idle if there is a process ready to run. Perhaps you want to find an alternative route for solving your *original* problem. Why do you need to give a process exclusive access to the CPU in the first place?

Comment: Can't you just use 'nice' to do mostly what you want?

Comment: Since there's only a "*single CPU core*", how would interrupts be serviced when a process has been given "*exclusive access to the cpu*"? Seem like you need to use accurate (and sensible) descriptions.

Comment: Kernel 2.4.x??? That was obsolete circa 2004. Why???

Answer (score 0):

When you test it, how much timer is set for interval? Probably set it to less than scheduling latency. I know of about 20ms for 2.6 linux kernel though check it and try with less than it. If this is the issue and code patch is fine, it most likely resolve it.

There can be alternative way to achieve this. Already SCHED_FIFO is available with system call to set process policy. This feature is addition to it with exact time it will execute until returns back to old policy. It means timer part could possibly implemented in userspace using event lib or any timer mechanism that suits your application and you do not need to hack kernel.

If it is just conceptually something to implement or any reason, one alternative way is to introduce new sched value like SCHED_FIFOTIMED and follow in cscope where scheduler policy fifo is introduced and create alternative option to FIFO. Have you tried round robin which address same thing as you want and there is no need for  kernel changes.